# Blank space between App Icon and Menu Icons

Tags: android

I want to make all my menu icons visible, hence I put android:showAsAction="ifRoom" and delete App title from the MainActivity.

But still all icons are not showing, rather there is a big gap between app icon and Menu icons as below. The rest of the icons are shown when I click on menu button (properties of ifRoom). So, can you please tell me how can I remove this big gap between App icon and Menu icons?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are restrictions, as [per the guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html):

> How many actions will fit in the main action bar? Action bar capacity is controlled by the following rules:
>
> Action buttons in the main action bar may not occupy more than 50% of the bar's width. Action buttons on bottom action bars can use the entire width.
> The screen width in density-independent pixels (dp) determine the number of items that will fit in the main action bar:
> smaller than 360 dp = 2 icons
> 360-499 dp = 3 icons
> 500-599 dp = 4 icons
> 600 dp and larger = 5 icons

You cannot fill the entire Action Bar with icons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your question. But you said two things, one you want to display all the icons in your `ActionBar`, and two you want to remove the "empty" space between icons and options menu.
Maybe I'm wrong so please can you clarify your question.
For the first question (display all the icons in your AB), you can't do this. But the solution may to create a `CustomView` in your `ActionBar`.

1. Disable the title
2. Disable the logo
3. Set a custom layout as: `actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.myactionbarview);`
4. Set the DisplayOptions: `actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)`

And to create an action on item click, you call your views like this:

```
MyIcon = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.myidicon);
MyIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do what you want
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.